# Embed a proxy script in a multiwan aggregation

Tags: proxy, openwrt

I currently admin a router running OpenWRT 15.05. The current setup involve 3 wans aggregated with the multiwan package available on the official opkg repos.

In those 3 wans, 2 are typical DSL access and 1 is coming from an other source which requires a proxy to use it. The problem is that the loadbalancer forwards requests to the most valuable connection of the 3 but it fails to load everytime it goes to that 3rd wan (because of the proxy issue). The proxy settings are given by a wpad server on its own subnet, if this can help.

How can i "absorb" the proxy settings into my router so my users don't have to configure anything ?

Thanks

Comment: Am I getting this correctly, that you want to find a way to automate the proxy logins for the 3rd WAN link ? If yes, it would be nice if you give the proxy type used there, how the manual login looks like ?

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz : well there is no configuration needed for a "high end" computer as it's given by the wpad server ; for a linux cli kindof device, a simple http_proxy env var is enough (i've been testing that with a raspberry pi)

Comment: Are you using multiwan or mwan3 package?

Comment: I'm not sure how this can work. If clients inside your network use the proxy configuration served by the wan3 router, they will use those settings for all connections, making wan1 and wan2 unused. You may be able to use the wan3 proxy transparently, making client configuration unnecessary. This could be done with iptables on the multiwan router. That will only work for ports handled by the wan3 proxy, so you would also need to configure policies in multiwan to only balance supported ports on wan3.

Comment: @EliHeady i'm using the multiwan package ; regarding your comment on _making client configuration unnecessary_ and _configure policies in multiwan_ that's exactly the goal ; i actually already made the policies so i just need to fix the proxy settings. should i consider iptable over interface configuration ? i think i should be able to use a `proxy` setting in `etc/config/network` or something ?